# Acceder a una imagen localhost por nodejs y express

Tags: nodejs, express, http

Tengo el backend que sirve unas Api REST.

Una de las API es para obtener usuarios

http://localhost:9000/users

Y lo pido por GET

el set de usuarios tiene una llave así

```
{ photo: myfoto.jpg }
```

Entonces cuando empiezo a armar la vista y a traer las imagenes, falla.

```
<img src="{{ url }}/uploads/users/{{ user.photo }}" alt="{{ user.name }} {{ user.last_name }}"
        class="img-fluid shadow-sm avatar100 ml-auto mr-auto d-block rounded-circle">
```

donde `url` tiene como valor http://localhost:9000 entonces la URL completa sería algo así

http://localhost:9000/uploads/users/myfoto.jpg

La foto existe, en dichas carpetas y con ese nombre, traté de pegarla directo en el navegador y está fue la respuesta

> Cannot GET /uploads/users/myfoto.jpg

Como si node estuviera tratando de ligar esto a una ruta, que, obviamente no existe en el archivo de rutas.

¿Cómo puedo jalar la foto? ¿Será un problema por que es localhost?

Agradezco su apoyo, si necesitan código lo puedo compartir, sinceramente no supe que parte del código es necesario compartir.

Comment: Hola, ¿has configurado Express para que sirva tus archivos estáticos? ¿Podrías explicar un poco la estructura de tus carpetas, para saber exactamente la ruta que contiene las imagenes que deseas servir? Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a servir contenido estático desde tu ordenador hacia internet deberás servirlo de alguna forma, ya sea con un ngnix o directamente con express de la siguiente forma.

```
app.use(express.static('/path/to/your/folder'));
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace que lo explica bien: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Podrías también compartir tu código para que podamos ayudarte mejor.